# Error when writing Pandas DataFrame to feather file

Tags: python, pandas, pyarrow, feather

While running:

```py
df.to_feather(file_path)
```

The following error occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "X:\FAKE\script.py", line 37, in df_to_feather
    df.to_feather(file_path)
  File "X:\FAKE\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 214, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "X:\FAKE\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1994, in to_feather
    to_feather(self, path)
  File "X:\FAKE\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\feather_format.py", line 64, in to_feather
    feather.write_feather(df, path)
  File "X:\FAKE\venv\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\feather.py", line 183, in write_feather
    writer.write(df)
  File "X:\FAKE\venv\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\feather.py", line 98, in write
    self.writer.write_array(name, col.chunk(0))
  File "pyarrow\feather.pxi", line 67, in pyarrow.lib.FeatherWriter.write_array
  File "pyarrow\error.pxi", line 105, in pyarrow.lib.check_status
pyarrow.lib.ArrowNotImplementedError: extension<pandas.period>
```

Any idea how to solve this would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last line:

```
pyarrow.lib.ArrowNotImplementedError: extension<pandas.period>
```

is telling you that the data type `pandas.Period` is currently not implemented for the feather format.  It is either a column or your index.  You can try converting it to the start/end of the period using `.asfreq()` method, or you can convert it to a timestamp using the `.to_timestamp()` method.

Comment: Thanks @James this solved my issue. Indeed there was a calculated column of type `Period[M]` in my DataFrame.

Comment: yes there was a cool down time for accepting answers. Cheers :)